# node.js: calling a function in webdriverio using mocha

Tags: node.js, selenium, mocha.js, webdriver-io

I am writing many test cases. In all of them there is a common part (signing in the user and doing some other stuff).

So instead of writing that part in every test, I want a function to call it.

I have tried using .then and .call but it throws error:

```
   .setValue('#signin_email', LogInEmail)
    ^
SyntaxError: Unexpected token .
```

How is this thing done?

Comment: Can you include more code? Especially the part before `.setValue`

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean this? http://webdriver.io/guide/usage/customcommands.html

```
browser.addCommand("LogInEmail", function () {
    return browser
      .setValue('#signin_email', 'emailaddress')
      .setValue('#password', 'password');
});

// to invoke
browser.LogInEmail()
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to run your common part before every mocha test then put it in beforeEach() function like this.

```
    describe('some test', function() {

     beforeEach(function() { 
            // your common part here     
       }); 

    it('it should do something, function() {
       ...
       });
       ...
    it('it should do something else', function() {
       ...
       });


   });
```